# NameError: name 'SourceBox' is not defined, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my program:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import requests
from tkinter import *


class App:
    
    #### LA BASE ####
    
    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("Tkinter News")
        #setting window size
        width=800
        height=500
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        GLabel_856=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_856["bg"] = "#d9b8ff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_856["font"] = ft
        GLabel_856["fg"] = "#d9b8ff"
        GLabel_856["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_856["text"] = ""
        GLabel_856.place(x=0,y=40,width=800,height=454)

        GLabel_339=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_339["bg"] = "#36264e"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=38)
        GLabel_339["font"] = ft
        GLabel_339["fg"] = "#be9ce6"
        GLabel_339["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_339["text"] = "Tkinter News"
        GLabel_339["relief"] = "raised"
        GLabel_339.place(x=0,y=0,width=800,height=80)

        GLabel_944=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_944["bg"] = "#1c1125"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_944["font"] = ft
        GLabel_944["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_944["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_944["text"] = ""
        GLabel_944.place(x=0,y=80,width=800,height=10)

        GLabel_580=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_580["bg"] = "#c4a1f8"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_580["font"] = ft
        GLabel_580["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_580["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_580["text"] = ""
        GLabel_580["relief"] = "sunken"
        GLabel_580.place(x=10,y=100,width=385,height=380)

        GLabel_129=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_129["bg"] = "#c7b9ff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_129["font"] = ft
        GLabel_129["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_129["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_129["text"] = ""
        GLabel_129["relief"] = "sunken"
        GLabel_129.place(x=410,y=100,width=385,height=380)

        GLabel_177=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_177["bg"] = "#000000"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_177["font"] = ft
        GLabel_177["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_177["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_177["text"] = ""
        GLabel_177.place(x=0,y=490,width=800,height=10)

        GButton_465=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_465["bg"] = "#fcbdbd"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=13)
        GButton_465["font"] = ft
        GButton_465["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_465["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_465["text"] = "Start"
        GButton_465.place(x=20,y=110,width=70,height=25)
        GButton_465["command"] = self.GButton_465_command

        
   

    

    #### APRES START ####
    def GButton_465_command(self):
        print("Start")
        
        
        
        GLineEdit_166=tk.Text(root)
        GLineEdit_166["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLineEdit_166["font"] = ft
        GLineEdit_166["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLineEdit_166.place(x=150,y=140,width=88,height=30)
        
        
        
        GLabel_858=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_858["bg"] = "#f491ff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=13)
        GLabel_858["font"] = ft
        GLabel_858["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_858["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_858["text"] = "Filtre"
        GLabel_858.place(x=110,y=110,width=216,height=25)

        GLabel_708=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_708["bg"] = "#eedbff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
        GLabel_708["font"] = ft
        GLabel_708["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_708["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_708["text"] = "Source"
        GLabel_708.place(x=20,y=140,width=120,height=30)

    
        
        GButton_669=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_669["bg"] = "#eedbff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_669["font"] = ft
        GButton_669["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_669["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_669["text"] = "Sources"
        GButton_669.place(x=20,y=450,width=70,height=20)
        GButton_669["command"] = self.GButton_669_command
        
        GButton_499=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_499["bg"] = "#f0f0f0"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_499["font"] = ft
        GButton_499["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_499["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_499["text"] = "Categories "
        GButton_499.place(x=100,y=450,width=70,height=20)
        GButton_499["command"] = self.GButton_499_command
        
        GLabel_233=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_233["activebackground"] = "#ba8cd9"
        GLabel_233["bg"] = "#f491ff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=13)
        GLabel_233["font"] = ft
        GLabel_233["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_233["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_233["text"] = "Disponibilité"
        GLabel_233.place(x=30,y=410,width=207,height=30)
        
        GButton_362=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_362["bg"] = "#f0f0f0"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_362["font"] = ft
        GButton_362["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_362["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_362["text"] = "Pays"
        GButton_362.place(x=180,y=450,width=70,height=20)
        GButton_362["command"] = self.GButton_362_command
        
        GButton_462=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_462["bg"] = "#f0f0f0"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_462["font"] = ft
        GButton_462["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_462["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_462["text"] = "Langues"
        GButton_462.place(x=260,y=450,width=70,height=20)
        GButton_462["command"] = self.GButton_462_command
        
        
        
        def Source_textbox_input():
            SourceBox=GLineEdit_166.get("1.0","end-1c")
            print(SourceBox)
        
       # buttonCommit=Button(root,width=10,height=1, text="Valider",command=lambda: retrieve_input())
       # buttonCommit.pack()
        
        GButton_491=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_491["bg"] = "#eedbff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_491["font"] = ft
        GButton_491["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_491["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_491["text"] = "Valider"
        GButton_491.place(x=250,y=140,width=68,height=30)
        GButton_491["command"] = lambda: Source_textbox_input()
        
        GButton_412=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_412["bg"] = "#eedbff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_412["font"] = ft
        GButton_412["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_412["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_412["text"] = "Afficher"
        GButton_412.place(x=322,y=140,width=68,height=30)
        GButton_412["command"] = self.GButton_412_command
        
        
    
        
    def GButton_412_command(self):
        print("afficher")
        def filtrer_par_source(nom): #FILTRE ARTICLE PAR SOURCE NOM
            """
            fonction qui filtre les recherches selon la source choisis
            """
            rien = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=,&br&apiKey=67d4540bfb764bc69b76e6f65298ab1f')
            listeurl = rien.split(',')
            #print(listeurl)
            url = str(listeurl[0] + nom + listeurl[1])
            #print(url)
            
            rep = requests.get(url)
            print(rep.json())
        
        filtrer_par_source(SourceBox)
    

 
        

    #### Fonction des boutons ####
        
############################# Disponible ##############################        

    def GButton_669_command(self):
        print("Source")
        
        def sources_dispo(): #AFFICHE LES SOURCES DISPONIBLES
            """
            fonction qui retourne le nom de toutes les sources disponibles
            """
            url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?'
                   'apiKey=67d4540bfb764bc69b76e6f65298ab1f')
            liste_source = []
            rep = requests.get(url)
            
            for i in rep.json()['sources']:
                liste_source.append(i['name'])
            return liste_source
            
        #print(sources_dispo())  

        
        #Afficher sources_dispo sur Tkinter
        GMessage_941=tk.Message(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=9)
        GMessage_941["font"] = ft
        GMessage_941["fg"] = "#333333"
        GMessage_941["justify"] = "center"
        GMessage_941["text"] = sources_dispo()
        GMessage_941.place(x=420,y=110,width=370,height=360)
        
   
           
    def GButton_499_command(self):
        print("Category")
        def category_dispo(): #AFFICHE LES CATEGORIES DISPONIBLES
            """
            fonction qui retourne toutes les categories disponibles 
            """
            url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?'
                   'apiKey=67d4540bfb764bc69b76e6f65298ab1f')
            liste_cat = []
            rep = requests.get(url)

            for i in rep.json()['sources']:
                liste_cat.append(i['category'])#ajout dans l'ensemble
            liste_cat = list(set(liste_cat))
            return liste_cat
    
        #Afficher category sur Tkinter
        GMessage_941=tk.Message(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
        GMessage_941["font"] = ft
        GMessage_941["fg"] = "#333333"
        GMessage_941["justify"] = "center"
        GMessage_941["text"] = category_dispo()
        GMessage_941.place(x=420,y=110,width=370,height=360)
        
    def GButton_362_command(self):
        print("Pays")
        def pays_dispo(): #AFFICHE LES PAYS DISPONIBLE                               
            """                                                                      
            fonction qui retourne les pays disponibles                               
            """                                                                      
            url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?'                   
                   'apiKey=67d4540bfb764bc69b76e6f65298ab1f')                        
            liste_pays = []                                                          
            rep = requests.get(url)                                                  

            
            for j in rep.json()['sources']:
                liste_pays.append(j['country'])
            liste_pays = list(set(liste_pays))
            return liste_pays
        
        #Afficher pays sur Tkinter
        GMessage_941=tk.Message(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
        GMessage_941["font"] = ft
        GMessage_941["fg"] = "#333333"
        GMessage_941["justify"] = "center"
        GMessage_941["text"] = pays_dispo()
        GMessage_941.place(x=420,y=110,width=370,height=360)
        
        
    def GButton_462_command(self):
        print("langues")
        def langues_dispo(): #AFFICHE LES LANGUES DISPONIBLES
            """
            fonction qui retourne toutes les langues disponibles 
            """
            url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines/sources?'
                   'apiKey=67d4540bfb764bc69b76e6f65298ab1f')
            liste_langues = []
            rep = requests.get(url)

            
            for i in rep.json()['sources']:
                liste_langues.append(i['language'])
            liste_langues = list(set(liste_langues))
            return liste_langues

        #print(langues_dispo())
        
        #Afficher langue sur Tkinter
        GMessage_941=tk.Message(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
        GMessage_941["font"] = ft
        GMessage_941["fg"] = "#333333"
        GMessage_941["justify"] = "center"
        GMessage_941["text"] = langues_dispo()
        GMessage_941.place(x=420,y=110,width=370,height=360)
        
   
            
############################## filtre ####################################
    
    
    
         
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

So it's a program that will return the source of an API news website
And we also have to make a filter system

It tells me `NameError: name 'SourceBox'` is not defined

Can anyone help me find the right place to put `def Source_textbox_input():`

So I tried to move the function several times but it gave me error messages each time

Comment: `SourceBox` is a local variable inside `Source_textbox_input()`.  It *doesn't exist* anywhere else in the program.  You've posted way too much code for me to figure out what this variable is supposed to do, so I have no specific suggestion on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As written, `SourceBox` is local to the method `Source_textbox_input()`. Do the following to make `SourceBox` available to all the methods in your `App` class

```
# add 'self.SourceBox' to the __init__ method
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        # not strictly necessary, but prevents issues if something tries to access
        # 'SourceBox` before it's created
        self.SourceBox = None  # default value
```

Modify the `Source_textbox_input()` function so it can access 'self'

```
def Source_textbox_input(self):
    self.SourceBox=GLineEdit_166.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(self.SourceBox)
```

Update the lambda bound to `Source_textbox_input`

```
GButton_491["command"] = lambda: Source_textbox_input(self)
```

And finally, you can now do this

```
filtrer_par_source(self.SourceBox)
```

And as an aside, refer to [PEP 8, the Python Style Guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) - your naming convention for variables and methods / functions goes against Python style practices.